# Another FTP daemon is already running?

Tags: xampp, osx-mavericks, proftpd

I'm running the xampp on os x mavericks
Xampp doesn't start the ProFTPD server.
when i tried to start it always failed.

In application log it says

```
 Starting ProFTPD...
 Checking syntax of configuration file
 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/proftpd/scripts/ctl.sh : proftpd started
```

Even after reinstalling the XAMPP ProFTPD doesn't start

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This happens when another FTP is running on the same port.

I also faced same issue, then i resolve this by doing following steps.

```
1. Open the file /Applications/XAMPP/etc/proftpd.conf

2. Search for the port "21" and change it to some other port (e.g 28).

3. Open the file /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp

4. Search for the port "testport 21" and replace it to "testport 28". 

5. Now go and run "sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp start". (It should work now).
```

Hope this Helps :)

Answer (score 2):

```
If you are Linux server, the the best and most quickly way is to do:
```

Step 1, Find the PID of ftp server (the second column), such as 21882, 22108....

```
ps aux | grep ftp
```

Step 2, kill these PID

```
sudo kill -9 21882
```